# Cant get face project to proporly work

Tags: modeling

I'm just trying to get this cylinder's face to snap to the box, but my efforts are futile, all setting lead to the same incorrect result. What am I doing wrong? All I yearn for is for these faces to align, but my day is in vain and pain. Every path I take leads me to this inevitable failure of an outcome, why is this world so cruel

[image]

Faces I want to align [image]

The result I'm always getting [image]

Outcome I'm trying to achieve [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just untick `Align Rotation to Target` in the snap options.

[image]

**Edit**: aligning the objects based on a specific face (rather than the whole object) takes more steps. This time `Align Rotation to Target` stays ticked.

- 1. Create an empty and snap (`Face Project`) it to the face of the cylinder you want to align. The empty adapts the face's orientation.
- 2. Make the empty the parent of the cylinder.
- 3. Flip the normal of the target face (enter face edit mode, select the target face and `Mesh > Normals > Flip`).
- 4. Go back to object mode, snap (`Face Project`) the empty to the target face, the cylinder should now have done what you desire.
- clean up: revert the normal flip, discard the empty

Note: i dont know why excactly, but if you don't flip the normals, the snap projection will be on the backside of the target faces.

[image]

Comment: thanks that does seem to fix the rotation problem I was having while aligning the faces with one another, however it doesn't seem to align the rotation of the object to the face Could you guide me on how to enable that feature as well?  https://imgur.com/CvmBK9A

Comment: @Dickhead_Jones Sry, i didnt realize you want to align the cylinder based on the specific face. I'll update my answer.